# Exporting keyframed Shape Keys to .gltf in Blender 2.80

Tags: animation, export, shape-keys, actions, gltf

I have been trying to export a sequence of shape keys that I imported from an .mdd file using the .gltf file format in Blender 2.80. I defined the sequence as an action in the shape key editor and checked sample all animations in the exporter, but when I import the created file back into Blender the shape keys are there but the animation is not. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

[The Blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cXX_10k5BZiC2UhoPVvH2ivgkJMLyWqf)

Answer (score 1):

I checked that file, I did that steps: exporting .mdd file, creating a new cube and imported previously created .mdd file. All works fine and animation works.

Comment: The issue was not the .mdd file but the .gltf file. For some reason blender couldn't see the animations in the .gltf file but a .gltf viewer could.